# How do I retain application data when I uninstall my iPhone application?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to remove a my iPhone application without removing my application's data?

Comment: Could you be more specific; ie: What Platform? What do you mean by local db?

Comment: @steve I think he specified iphone in the tags, so isn't it obvious

Comment: @robin: He didn't. In fact, there was absolutely no mention of iOS in the original question. It was just a question about an "objective-c application".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store local data after user delete my iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180226/how-to-store-local-data-after-user-delete-my-ios-app)

Answer (score 6):

No it is not possible. You can always implement a remote backup service such as Dropbox.

Once a user taps the `x` to remove an app from the Springboard, all of the data is removed. Remote backup is your best option.